# Postgres c# listen timeout

Tags: c#, postgresql, listen, tcp-keepalive

I'm using Postgres 9.5 which has a feature called `LISTEN/NOTIFY` that allows you to set up an asynchronous command channel to get notifications from the server. For the first 10-15 minutes when my application runs and I test the notifications everything seems to work, but after there's certain amount of time the messages just seems to be dropped.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what can prevent this behavior? Does this have anything to do with keep alive / tcp keep alive settings? In pg_state_activity I'm seeing that same connection and it's in idle state.

General rundown of the situation

- Using npgsql library in c# to an off-site Postgresql server
- Using a long-running connection (setup listen, wait)
- Executing a query to listen for incoming notices and notifications
- Waiting (with a cancelation token) until a message is received (no other activity happens on connection).

Looking through some of the other answers on StackOverflow, it seems people also attribute this to pooling, though I'm not completely sure this translates well to `npgsql` since it pools connections on connect / disconnects.

I would appreciate any insights people have regarding this problem, anybody have an idea how I can make my situation work? Here's a snippet of code that's the culprit: https://gist.github.com/phr34k/3a59af154d8ce6636dfc332271052a6a

**Edit**

In response to jjanes's reply, I went to further investigate. When I look in `pg_state_activity` it lists the connection in idle state. When I cross-reference the client port number with `netstat -t` on the server at least I don't see connection listed.

To be fair, before I ran `netstat -t` i did attempt an `pg_notify` so I can't be sure yet if maybe running `pg_notify` didn't cause it to terminate. However, the weird thing is that the connection keeps showing up in `pg_state_activity` as-if postgres didn't even realize the connection was closed?

I think this has something to do with firewalls and idle connections. Anybody know if there's anything default in ubuntu/digital ocean stack that kills connections after a while?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything will make a connection stop listening, without calling UNLISTEN or closing.  The most likely explanation is the connection is severed, and then the connection pool papers over this by re-establishing the connection, in which case the new connection would not be listening.  This event should be logged, both on the client side and the probably the server side.  Do you see anything in the logs that seems to make sense in this context?

'idle' is the normal "state" in pg_stat_activity of something which is doing nothing but listening, so that isn't going to help you.  But the "backend_start" column might help, is that consistent with the connection being closed and re-opened?  The "state_change" might at first seem promising but that doesn't seem to get updated merely upon the client reading a notification.  I don't see a way for one session to detect if any other sessions are listening.  pg_listening_channels() only works for the connection that issues it.

> Waiting (with a cancelation token) until a message is received (no other activity happens on connection).

Is the cancellation token significant?  Do you ever use it?  Could the share the snippet of code that implements this wait?

I don't think 10 or 15 minutes is long enough for TCP to be deciding the connection is dead, so if the connection is getting severed it is more likely something actively doing it, like a firewall.  If that is the case, it may "see through" the keep alive and decide to drop the connection anyway.

Comment: Here's the culprit https://gist.github.com/phr34k/3a59af154d8ce6636dfc332271052a6a

I checked pg_stat_activity and I couldn't really find anything suspicious at first glance; the connection is in idle, so I manually tried to send the notification from pgAdmin and nothing was received;  I also tried to terminate the connection in that state which was also not picked up. I have TCP KeepAlive enabled in the connection.

Comment: The cancelation token is not significant, I basically use the token so I can safely shutdown the code for when I move this into a service component (start/stop events). However, I just do a single wait/listen, and not periodically reentrant after some timeout- i'm not sure if that makes my code more sensitive to this kind of "severance" problem.

Comment: I didn't understand what did you do to prevent the behaviour that you mentioned. I too came across this issue. I used Tcp Keepalive Time=val1 and Tcp Keepalive Interval=val2 to set the time that defines the maximum interval between two successive notifications. Any notification after this time interval is not received.